# eval throwing exception Use of undefined constant in php

Tags: php, eval

I'm using eval to make decision using string value. When i trying to compare two string it will throwing exception Use of undefined constant. Please help anybody what wrong with this.

```
$condition ="no != no";
echo eval("return $condition;");
```

throwing error like

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant no - assumed 'no' in index.php : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: There's a reason why everyone says that `eval()` is *evil* :-) It's dangerous to use!

Comment: What else should that code do? What would happen if you write that plain, like `return no != no`?

Answer (score 2):

no should be a variable like `$no != $no` where `$no` should have predefined value or it should be a string like below:

```
$condition ="'no' != 'no'";
echo eval("return $condition;");
```

But please note that you should never use eval in any case as it is really a bad option. Please avoid that and you can use below code to achieve your requirement:

```
return ('no' != 'no') ? false: true;
```

Hope it clears you.